# the io.input() method of lua did'nt work for user input

Tags: lua

I still coding my project, and to got the user input I used io.input("*l") method to this
and worked very well, but for some reason it didn't work anymore.
The error message say:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua.exe: .\nexus\guilogin.lua:16: bad argument #1 to 'input' (*l: Invalid argument)`

I tryied search about it and I don't find anything about this error or how to fix this

the source of the script I still having this issue

```lua
strx = require 'pl.stringx'
wv = require 'src.nxwvinit'
ntutils = require 'src.nativeutils'
filesys = require 'src.nxfilesys'
workspace = require 'nexus.workspace'

local read = 1

login = {}
wvsrc = "nexus/windview/"


function login.init()
    active = 1
    while active == 1 do
        userLogin = io.input("*l")
        if userLogin ~= nil or userLogin ~= "" then
            if checkUserExist(userLogin) ~= nil then
                workspace.init()
            else
                print("Eat shit")
            end
        else
            print("insert valid username")
        end
    end
end

-- check if user folder exists
function checkUserExist(username)
    directory = "users"
    curDir = io.popen("dir " .. directory .. "/b /ad")
    dirLines = curDir:lines()
    for dir in dirLines do
        if string.find(dir, username) then
            return username
        else
            return nil
        end
    end
end

return login
```

Comment: `if userLogin ~= nil or userLogin ~= "" then` - There should be `and` instead of `or`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong function.
`io.input` expects a filename.
You probably need `io.read` to read a line of input text.

Comment: the io.input a working very well but for some reason it didn't work anymore.